# Notification bubbles not appearing on iPhone X

Tags: firebase, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application written in Xamarin.ios and has FCM for notifications and they are working flawlessly on every iPhone except for iPhone X and relatives (Xs, Xs, Xr).

The problem is that the System notification bubbles are not appearing on these devices when a notification arrives (but on the other devices they work great)

I noticed that the `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` function is not being called on iPhone X family, neither the `DidReceiveNotificationResponse`, which is correctly called on regular devices.

I already configured `UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate`.

Any ideas that could work on Swift 4 should work as well since the Xamarin.iOS is really similar to Swift 4.

I expect that the System notification bubbles appear when I receive a FCM notification

Comment: Which system version of  iPhone X and relatives (Xs, Xs, Xr),also you can post some code about notifications in `AppDelegate.cs`.

Comment: I found the solution and posted in a different answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS nuget has no support for ARMv7/ARMv7s architectures. I went into Options -> iOS Build -> Supported architectures and then select ARM64 alone, this way the notifications are now received on iPhone X and others.

This works for now but is a solution that might reduce the compatibility of an app with certain devices, so should be used with precaution.